# MPMoviePlayerController perfectly works with Ios 4.0 but not working in 4.2

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have implement the MPMoviePlayerController it perfectly working in ios 3.2 and 4.0 but not in Ios 4.2.

***What i'm wrong with my code***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSLog(@"videoSubView viewDidLoad");


moviePlayerController =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:videoURL];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayerController];   
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayerController];   

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayerController];


moviePlayerController.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);     

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];


[moviePlayerController play];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

added the MediaPlayer.framework and #import  import the mediaplayer in .h file

Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is displayed within the player window?

Comment: @Till: it shows nothing not even the player window, i m facing same problem!

Comment: Move that `[super viewDidLoad]` to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly intialised `videoURL` ?

Comment: Does not seem to qualify as an answer.

Comment: I disagree - this was actually exactly the problem that I was having myself.

Answer (score 0):

How are you initialising videoURL? I was having this problem in iOS 5.0 only. Once I changed from doing this:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:localFile];
```

to this:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFile];
```

the problem went away.